# Composite Indicator - Negative Correlation Issue

Tags: correlation, pca, aggregation, synthetic-data

I'm trying to build a composite indicator that aims to measure poverty. I'm planning to aggregate a series of variables using PCA. However I have a doubt, all the variables I want to include are positively correlated except for one (GDP is negatively correlated with all the other "poverty" variables). Is this going to be a problem when aggregating the variables? Is there a way in which I can solve this problem that does not include simply getting rid of the GDP variable?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I would say try, then ask for help.

I do not see why this should be a problem. If you do a PCA and then you discover that a set of variables are positively correlated and one is negatively correlated to a latent factor, you could create an indicator variable  where the negative correlated variable has a negative weight, while the other variables have a positve weight.